# How to implement a filter for RecyclerView populated from Firestore?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

Real-time filtering RecyclingView populated from Firestore by replacing adapter with updated query shows really poor performance.

To filter `RecyclerView` in my app in real time(`onQueryTextChange`) I am using custom adapter that extends `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` and every time I need to filter data I create a new `Query` object, create new `FirestoreRecyclerOptions` object then create my custom adapter object where I pass `FirestoreRecyclerOptions` object to `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` constructor and finally I call `swapAdapter` on my `RecyclerView`. The problem with this approach is that it results in a poor performance. I can see the view blinking every time the query is updated.

**DocumentSearchActivity.java**

```
package com.example.testapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.view.animation.LayoutAnimationController;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.testapp.adapter.ItemAdapter;
import com.example.testapp.model.Item;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;

public class DocumentSearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = DocumentSearchActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private ItemAdapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private TextView mNoResultsTextView;
    private SearchView mSearchView;
    private FirestoreQuery mQuery;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_document_search);
        mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mSearchView = findViewById(R.id.search_bar);
        mNoResultsTextView = findViewById(R.id.result);
        mNoResultsTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if(getIntent().hasExtra(MainActivity.QUERY_EXTRA)){
            mSearchView.setQuery(getIntent().getStringExtra(MainActivity.QUERY_EXTRA), true);
            mSearchView.requestFocus();
        }

        mQuery = new FirestoreQuery(this, "");
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            mQuery.setQueryString(intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY));
        }

        mAdapter = new ItemAdapter(mQuery.getOptions());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                mAdapter = new ItemAdapter(mQuery.setQueryString(newText).getOptions());
                mRecyclerView.swapAdapter(mAdapter, true);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mAdapter.startListening();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private void runLayoutAnimation(final RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        final Context context = recyclerView.getContext();
        final LayoutAnimationController controller =
                AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(context, R.anim.layout_animation_fall_down);

        recyclerView.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
        recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        recyclerView.scheduleLayoutAnimation();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.actions_document_search_activity, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    private class FirestoreQuery {
        private LifecycleOwner mLifecycleOwner;
        private String mQueryString;
        private Query mQuery;
        private FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Item> mOptions;

        public FirestoreQuery(LifecycleOwner lifecycleOwner, String query) {
            mLifecycleOwner = lifecycleOwner;
            setQueryString(query);
        }

        public FirestoreQuery setQueryString(String queryString) {
            if(queryString.length() != 0)
                this.mQueryString = queryString.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + queryString.substring(1).toLowerCase();
            else
                this.mQueryString = queryString;
            updateQuery();
            updateOptions();
            return this;
        }

        private void updateOptions() {
            mOptions = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Item>()
                    .setQuery(mQuery, Item.class)
                    .setLifecycleOwner(mLifecycleOwner)
                    .build();
        }

        private void updateQuery() {
            if(mQueryString.isEmpty()){
                this.mQuery = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                        .collection("tubes_test")
                        .orderBy("number");
            } else {
                StringBuilder query_lower = new StringBuilder(mQueryString.length());
                query_lower.append(mQueryString);
                query_lower.setCharAt(mQueryString.length() - 1, (char) (query_lower.charAt(mQueryString.length() - 1) + 1));
                if (mQueryString.matches("^[0-9]{1,3}[A-Z]*$")) {
                    this.mQuery = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                            .collection("tubes_test")
                            .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("number", mQueryString)
                            .whereLessThan("number", query_lower.toString());
                } else {
                    this.mQuery = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                            .collection("tubes_test")
                            .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("name", mQueryString)
                            .whereLessThan("name", query_lower.toString());
                }
            }
        }

        public FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Item> getOptions() {
            return mOptions;
        }

    }
}
```

**ItemAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.testapp.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.testapp.DocumentViewerActivity;
import com.example.testapp.R;
import com.example.testapp.model.Item;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;

public class ItemAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Item, ItemAdapter.ItemHolder> {

    public ItemAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Item> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ItemHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Item item) {
        final String tubeNumber = item.getNumber();
        holder.mNumberTextView.setText(item.getNumber());
        holder.mNameTextView.setText(item.getName());
        holder.mFormulaTextView.setText(item.getFormula());
        holder.mRangeTextView.setText(item.getRange());
        holder.mInfoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), DocumentViewerActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("number", tubeNumber);
                intent.putExtra("doctype", "info");
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        holder.mManualButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), DocumentViewerActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("number", tubeNumber);
                intent.putExtra("doctype", "manual");
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        Context context = viewGroup.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        View tubeView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_tube, viewGroup, false);

        return new ItemHolder(tubeView);
    }

    public static class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView mNumberTextView;
        public TextView mNameTextView;
        public TextView mFormulaTextView;
        public TextView mRangeTextView;
        public Button mInfoButton;
        public Button mManualButton;

        public ItemHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);

            mNumberTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.number);
            mNameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            mFormulaTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.formula);
            mRangeTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.range);
            mInfoButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.info_btn);
            mManualButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.manual_btn);
        }
    }
}
```

I wonder if there is a better way to solve this problem. Also, I don't want to lose sweet Firestore functionality such as live data updates and offline access to the database. I was thinking about using a filterable List in my adapter, the question is how do i keep it in sync with Firestore. Please share your insights and guidelines.

Comment: How many records you're trying to filter?

Comment: How many objects does your query return? Please responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo Overall, I have about 400 records in the databases, depending on the query it might be anything between 400 and 0

Comment: @JoaquinAlvarez please see above

Comment: Is it true that when returning 10 records works good and when returning 400 is slow?

Comment: @AlexMamo no, it looks like it is always the same delay

Comment: Even if you are calling `limit(1)`? If yes, please edit your question and add the code that you are using.

Comment: @AlexMamo yes, even if i'm calling limit(1)

Comment: @aglazkov *results in a poor performance* - You're creating an adapter each time there's a change in that query so there will be a lot of remeasuring and relayout passes in the layout. Looking at the code of FirestoreRecyclerAdapter it seems it's just for displaying data, it doesn't allow a direct change in FirestoreRecyclerOptions. In this case you'll need to use a regular RecyclerView.Adapter with a filter on it and manually do the query on firestore.

Comment: @Luksprog thank you for you comment. I understand that swapping adapter every time query changes affects performance. Also, I was thinking about using regular adapter.  _"The question is how do i keep it in sync with Firestore?"_ Should I implement some kind of listener that will listen for updates in Firestore and update my List in adapter accordingly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution that worked for me. Basically, I created a custom filterable adapter that I populate with data from Firestore once only.

**CustomItemAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.testapp.adapter;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.testapp.DocumentViewerActivity;
import com.example.testapp.R;
import com.example.testapp.model.Item;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CustomItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomItemAdapter.ItemHolder> implements Filterable {

    private List<Item> mTubeList;
    private List<Item> mTubeListFiltered;

    public CustomItemAdapter(List<Item> tubeList){
        mTubeList = tubeList;
        mTubeListFiltered = tubeList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View tubeView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_tube, viewGroup, false);
        return new ItemHolder(tubeView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ItemHolder holder, int i) {
        final Item item = mTubeListFiltered.get(i);
        //Setting up view
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mTubeListFiltered.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                String pattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                if(pattern.isEmpty()){
                    mTubeListFiltered = mTubeList;
                } else {
                    List<Item> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for(Item tube: mTubeList){
                        if(tube.getNumber().toLowerCase().contains(pattern) || tube.getName().toLowerCase().contains(pattern)) {
                            filteredList.add(tube);
                        }
                    }
                    mTubeListFiltered = filteredList;
                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = mTubeListFiltered;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                mTubeListFiltered = (ArrayList<Item>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }

    public static class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        //ViewHolder's code
    }
}
```

Snippet from Activity:

```
        Query query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                .collection("test")
                .orderBy("number");
        query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                mAdapter = new CustomItemAdapter(task.getResult().toObjects(Item.class));
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            }
        });
        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                mAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Out of interest, have you since solved this problem for paged data? (I'm curious how to solve for a very large data set, e.g. millions of objects; I cannot download them all to filter on the client)

Comment: Best way is to save data on separate database e.g. mongo db with document Id and do filtering there or use third party tools such as Algolia to search for your document. It is impossible for complex queries to run on firestore. @AjahnCharles